# Web deploy deleting SMTP configs from IIS

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

When deploying my asp.net website to IIS using Web deploy, my previously configured SMTP settings (in my IIS application) are erased. I know I can set this settings in web.config but i don't want to.

Comment: You could use config file transformations if the values need to be different during Debug vs. Release. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or use WebDeploy Parameterization which occurs at deploy time instead of build time for Config Transforms.